# не работает горизонтальный скролл при добавлении JTable на JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, gui, jtable, jscrollpane

Я добавляю JTable на JScrollPane. Ставлю режим

```
setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);
```

Что бы таблица занимала весь скролл. Когда столбцов мало - все красиво, они растягиваются  и занимают всю ширину скролла. Но если их много, то они сужаются и самое и выглядит это не красиво:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Можно конечно задать минимальную ширину для каждого столбца:

```
getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setMinWidth(75);
```

Получается так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но тут появляется еще одна проблема. Не работает горизонтальный скролл. Режим стоит `setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);`
Скролл то есть, но прокручивать его нельзя. Знаю, что можно решить все эти проблемы следующим кодом:

```
setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
```

Но тогда столбцы и расширятся перестают и таблица прижимается к левому верхнему углу скролла. В общем, мне надо что бы когда столбцов мало - то они расширялись на всю ширину скролла, а когда их много - что бы они не сужались меньше определенного значения. И что бы горизонтальный скролл работал. Можно как-нибудь это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

За взаимодействие с `JScrollPane` отвечает интерфейс `javax.swing.Scrollable`.

В [ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6104955) участника [camickr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/131872/camickr) на en.SO показано, как переопределить метод `getScrollableTracksViewportWidth` у `JTable`, чтобы добиться нужного результата:

```
public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportWidth() {
    return getPreferredSize().width < getParent().getWidth();
};
```

Метод возвращает `true`, если панель прокрутки должна установить ширину таблицы по размеру видимого окна (viewport).

Решение доработано в [другом ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15240806), т.к. без доработки нельзя было менять ширину первой колонки, если размер таблицы не превышал размер видимой области.